# Can't connect to Oracle DB via JDBC on java desktop app

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, database-connection

I was trying to create a very simple app where at loading the main window the program connects to the DB.

If I comment the part of the connection to the DB it works fine. The app shows no error, throws no exception, so I cannot figure out what's wrong. I post my code:

```
public final class Database {
    private final String dbURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + dbHost + ":" + dbPort + ":" + dbService;
    private final String dbDriver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
    private Connection connection = null;

    public Database() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Aqui 1");
            Class.forName(dbDriver);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Database.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    private void connect() {
        System.out.println("Dentro");
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, dbUser, dbPass);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Database.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    private void disconnect() {
        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Database.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public void numeroErrores(String dependencia){
        System.out.println("Hola");
        connect();
        disconnect();
        System.out.print("Adios");
    }
}
```

the dbUser, dbPass, dbHost, dbPort, dbService are set to their correct value, I've checked and rechecked them, also I am sure I've added the correct jar file of the oracle-jdbc. It kind of hangs (I say kind of 'cause no error no nothing is shown but the System.out.println I put there) when calling the `connect()` method.

Any idea?

Comment: How are you debugging this? We need some sort of exception.

Comment: There's no exception, no nothing, I'm working in NetBeans and used its debugger to see if I could see something but nope... Any idea to see what's wrong? Something I could look into the debugging to post it here?

Comment: Are you sure the port is open (Firewall - local or somewhere in between) and the listener accepts remote connections from your host? I often use java based query tools to make sure remote connections via java work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are not enough debug prints or catch statements
Try catching both general Exception and Throwable, see if that adds data
If you dont have a debugger, add debug prints on every line so you know exactly where you are
If you have the ojdbc6.jar, try adding this right before DriverManager.getConnection:

> DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver());

just to make sure

Comment: Tried with general Exception and Throwable and there aren't any messages at all. I'm using the ojdbc6.jar and tried with the line you posted and nothing. Using some prints I found the before `connection = DriverManager.getConnection()` it works fine but for some reason the program never passes that line, maybe a loop inside the `getConnection()` method.

Comment: the timeout for the connection can be very long - up to a few minutes. you can wait 3 to 5 minutes and see if you get connection timeout. can you ping the db machine ?

Comment: I'll let the app run till something (hopefully) shows. The db machine is ok I am making some queries using sqlDeveloper. I'll post if the timeout shows.

Comment: Indeed, `IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection`.

Comment: this is a regular connection problem, either ip or port are wrong. try maybe using the server name instead of an ip, or the other way

Comment: I see. Thanks for the advise. I'll check it even though I'm pretty sure my connection params are right. I was freaked out 'cause no error shown immediatly but now I know where to look.

Comment: please let us know how it worked out and if the answer was helpful.

Comment: Finally It worked, no one told me that IP's changed I used the name of the db-machine. Thanks for your help.